# modulus behaving differently on different servers? (with / without spaces)

Tags: php

The following code

```
<?php
echo ((12+1)%12)."<br/>";
echo ((12+1) % 12)."<br/>";
?>
```

leads to an unexpected result (13,1) instead of (1,1) on phpfiddle.org but it runs as expected on my server.

http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/qdb-s4t

Is this an error in their sandbox or does it have to do with different php versions? How is the case without spaces interpreted?

I was just looking at some code for quite a long time and couldn't understand what was the difference.
i know i could use fmod or other sandboxes like http://ideone.com/.

Comment: the first line in your js fiddle is missing `%12`

Comment: thanks for the comment.%12 is only missing after saving the fiddle. so it's an error in the sandbox

Comment: yeah, its definitely not version based. how totally odd though.

Comment: phpfiddle is parsing the code first from the browser - your server is interpreting the PHP like it's supposed to, there's obviously just a bug in the phpfiddle parser.

Comment: i've sent feedback to the operators of phpfiddle.org. can you add this as answer to the question?

Comment: It seems the phpfiddle is not parsing correctly the modulo sign when it don't have spaces around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPFiddle is just a website that is attempting to provide an easy way to execute PHP code samples from the browser. This isn't going to give you native behavior, simply because the code is going to be processed by JavaScript first using whatever logic the people at PHPFiddle seem fit. This leads to the possibility of bugs that have nothing to do with PHP and that is what is going on here. If you turn those same lines of codes into full strings, you will see the output still isn't even correct.